# How to create an if else condition that selects specific names in vectors from three different dataframes?

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, character

I need to extract rows from a large dataframe specifying only the first name or last name, but I need to check this in three different dataframes.
I believe I'm making a grotesque mistake, but I'm spending hours and I can't solve it.

I used this code, but I get an error.

- A reproducible model.

  ```
  df1 <- data.frame(NAME1=c("MARIA APARECIDA", "JOSÉ CARLOS", "PEDRO PAULO BRAZ", "MÁRCIO TEELES","HUGO HOSEMAN"),
                   col2=c("CONTROL", "EXPERIMENT", "EXPERIMENT", "CONTROL", "CONTROL"),
                   col3 = c("none", "none", "none", "none", "none"))

  df2 <- data.frame(NAME2=c("MARIA APARECIDA", "JOSÉ NONATO ", "PAULO BRAZ CUNHA", "ALAN SIMON","BRITNEY HALLEN"),
                    col2=c("CONTROL", "EXPERIMENT", "CONTROL", "CONTROL", "EXPERIMENT"),
                    col3 = c("none", "none", "none", "none", "none"))

  df3 <- data.frame(NAME3=c("MERLY MATOS", "OSVALDO SIQUEIRA ", "ITANYA MARIA LOPES", "ZILCA COSTA","DIVONE FERRAZ"),
                    col2=c("EXPERIMENT", "CONTROL", "EXPERIMENT", "CONTROL", "CONTROL"),
                    col3 = c("none", "none", "none", "none", "none"))  

      name<- "MARIA"

       if (filter(grepl(df1$NAME1== name))) {
    unique(grep(name, df1$NAME1, value = TRUE))


  } else if (grep(df2$NAME2== name)){
    unique(grep(name, df2$NAME2, value = TRUE))

  } else {
    unique(grep(name, df3$NAME3, value = TRUE))
  }



   Error in grepl(df1$NAME1 == name) : 
   argument "x" is missing, with no default
  ```

Comment: Are you using `dplyr::filter`, or is that `stats::filter`? (Both uses are incorrect as you've got it, btw.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (no need for `filter`).

```r
name <- "MARIA"
if (length(nm1 <- grep(name, df1$NAME1, value=TRUE))) {
  unique(nm1)
} else if (length(nm2 <- grep(name, df2$NAME2, value=TRUE))) {
  unique(nm2) 
} else {
  unique(grep(name, df3$NAME3, value=TRUE))
}
# [1] "MARIA APARECIDA"
```

As to what you were doing incorrectly: `dplyr::filter` takes as its first argument a frame, and its second and subsequent arguments should be conditionals. It will return 0 or more rows of a frame. Because we'll be using `filter(df1, ...)`, we also don't need to include the `df1$` with the name.

To adapt your code (though I don't think it adds anything), you might do

```r
if (nrow(filter(df1, grepl(name, NAME1))) > 0) {
  unique(grep(name, df1$NAME1, value = TRUE))
} else if (nrow(filter(df2, grepl(name, NAME2))) > 0) {
  unique(grep(name, df2$NAME2, value = TRUE))
} else {
  unique(grep(name, df3$NAME3, value = TRUE))
}
# [1] "MARIA APARECIDA"
```

For this, we're doing a bit more work than needed, namely at least two `grep`s and a `filter` that is not strictly needed.

Since you're dealing with multiple frames and they are similarly structured, you might consider keeping them in a [list of frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227).

```r
dflist <- list(df1, df2, df3)
res <- lapply(dflist, function(df) unique(grep(name, df[[grep("NAME", names(df))]], value=TRUE)))
res
# [[1]]
# [1] "MARIA APARECIDA"
# [[2]]
# [1] "MARIA APARECIDA"
# [[3]]
# [1] "ITANYA MARIA LOPES"
res[lengths(res) > 0][[1]]
# [1] "MARIA APARECIDA"
```

In this case, we are `grep`ing for all frames even if we find something in `df1`, so a little less-awesome in efficiency, but we gain the ability to define a single expression to be called on all frames without copy/paste. (It does suffer a little because we're looking for different `NAME#` in each; if your data are really identically-named, then this gets even easier.)

---

For your request for the whole row, I suggest instead of *going back* to the frame(s) to find the individual row(s), we just retrieve them to begin with.

```r
rowsfound <- 
  if (nrow(found1 <- filter(df1, grepl(name, NAME1)))) {
    found1
  } else if (nrow(found2 <- filter(df2, grepl(name, NAME2)))) {
    found2
  } else {
    filter(df3, grepl(name, NAME3))
  }
rowsfound
#             NAME1    col2 col3
# 1 MARIA APARECIDA CONTROL none
```

or using the list-of-frames:

```r
res <- lapply(dflist, function(z) z[grepl(name, z[[grep("NAME", names(z), value=TRUE)]]),])
res
# [[1]]
#             NAME1    col2 col3
# 1 MARIA APARECIDA CONTROL none
# [[2]]
#             NAME2    col2 col3
# 1 MARIA APARECIDA CONTROL none
# [[3]]
#                NAME3       col2 col3
# 3 ITANYA MARIA LOPES EXPERIMENT none
res[sapply(res, nrow) > 0][[1]]
#             NAME1    col2 col3
# 1 MARIA APARECIDA CONTROL none
```

Comment: Thank you very much, both codes work great. You really helped me and were very clear in your explanation

Comment: IS there any way to select row from dataframe  list by the name found above?

Comment: I had already tried this code before, but it retun me  this error:  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: That makes no sense given the sample data: there is nothing in this code that assumes numeric or integer or string or anything, it seems likely that the error is from something you're doing outside of this step.

Comment: I'm sorry, I really got lost in the code and I was running it wrong. Thank you again, you've helped me a lot.